# route all passing traffic on port 80 over router to external squid system

Tags: iptables, routing, squid

I'm unable to find correct iptables lines for this.

I have a router who has one or more wlan clients (wlan0/10.13.37.x). 
eth0 is connected to the internet (through other routers).
Squid is accessible over VPN (tun0/172.27.0.1).

All http requests passing the router, should be redirected to 172.27.0.1:8080.

Squid is set as transparant proxy.

Thanks

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.13 on Tue Apr 24 00:45:14 2012
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:328]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:164]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:164]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 24 00:45:14 2012
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.13 on Tue Apr 24 00:45:14 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [50:6468]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [149:28841]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 222 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4949 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 0:1023 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 0:1023 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4949 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -d 10.13.37.0/24 -i wlan0 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 10.13.37.0/24 -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.13.37.0/24 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Apr 24 00:45:14 2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure iptables solution:

```
# redirect to squid
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src 10.13.37.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport http \
         -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.0.1:8080

# route clients to squid
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t filter -I FORWARD --src 10.13.37.0/24 --dst 172.27.0.1 \
         -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 \
         -j ACCEPT

iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
         -j ACCEPT

# masquerade (snat) clients in case the VPN doesn't know about the LAN
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Another solution based on iptables and [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat) in case you don't want to mess too much with iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --src 10.13.37.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport http \
         -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,bind=127.0.0.1,fork TCP4:172.27.0.1:8080
```

Comment: Doesn't work. My clients are now unable to access http sites. In chrome: Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

Comment: The rule is fine, you might have a problem with your routes between the VPN endpoint and the local network. What happen if you ping from a workstation to the Squid server? This should work if you want to use that rule.

Comment: @Tuinslak: if you setup the proxy explicitly in Chrome (or any other browser) does it work?

Comment: Yes (while not using the VPN ip, but the public IP)

Comment: I can indeed not ping the VPN network from a wlan device.

Comment: @Tuinslak: what about the second solution?

Comment: I'm afraid that one isn't routing it either. I can access HTTP content, but it's not passing through Squid.

Comment: If I use Socat, I'm able to telnet 10.10.10.1:8080 and see a Squid reply. But I can only do that once, after that Socat stops working (so can't set it as browser proxy). Might be handy to know this is a armhf device running Wheezy.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that `socat` allowed only one connection at a time, but the *fork* option should fix that.

Comment: I've updated my original post to include the iptables rules I'm starting from (there might be an error in those) and I changed the IPs with the real IPs i'm using. I'd rather not use socat if possible.

Comment: Does the new answer work? If not, what happens with the counters of iptables rules from the answer i.e. some of them increase or not?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply (due to other stuff to do and wifi/driver issue having to be fixed first). first part still doesn't work. 2nd part gives me a "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name." but apparently even the most basic iptables rules gives me that (with prerouting), where on another server (not ARMHF) it works fine. So might be an ARM/iptables bug on that arch. I'll try to get some info

Comment: Maybe your ARMHF kernel isn't compiled with iptables support or is missing the modules required by these rules, e.g. `libipt_MASQUERADE.ko` for `MASQUARADE`.

Comment: Yes, apparently my hardware provider changed some important kernel parameters. I'm waiting for them to compile a new kernel and will get back to this. Thanks so far.

Comment: Yes, finally could try it again. The first solution seems to work perfectly now. Thanks. :)